# html file still pointing to jsp file instead of servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have three files, The first one is called **index.html**, the other is **des.jsp** and the last one is called **addEmailListServlet**.

In the past when user insert his data in the form the html file sent them to the des.jsp but now I want the data to be sent to the servlet class so I changed the action parameter in the html to point to the servlet and I wrote the web.xml file and I deleted cache but nothing is working still sending the user to the wrong file.

here is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/addEmailListServlet" method="post">
        <table cellspacing="5"  border="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">name:<input type="text" name="name"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">surname:<input type="text" name="surname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">email:<input type="text" name="email"/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="submit"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

as you can see the action in the form is sending the user to addEmailListServlet but this is not happening now take look at web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>addEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>email.addEmailListServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>addEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/addEmailListServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I think there is no need to look at servlet file.

Comment: Have you rebuilt **and** redeployed your website? Are there any errors?

Comment: Also, unless your app is deployed as the root webapp, the action should be `addEmailListServlet` (without the leading slash).

Comment: i did what you saying 100 time but now it work ! thank you